# Allow "Ask Question" for companies that don't allow "Easy Apply"

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Companies that allow you to "Easy Apply" give you the option to ask them a question as shown:

[image]

Companies that don't allow candidates to "Easy Apply" don't allow you to ask a question:

[image]

For these type of companies I believe we should still allow candidates to ask a question, even if we change the functionality such that these employers just get an email?

The reason I ask for this is I was trying to apply for a company that did not have an "Easy Apply" and their application process is broken.  The site isn't working correctly.  It would have been nice to click "Ask a question" to this company (and even if they were not using the SO employers side UI) to ask the responsible person for that company a question.  Currently I cannot do that.

Feature request to still allow this popup to come up and simply change the mechanism of how the company gets it.  In this case if they do not use the employer version of so jobs maybe they just get an email...

Comment: Interesting! I'd think it's more important to ask a question when there is no easy apply in the first place.

Comment: @MattR - I agree with you...either way I'd like to see this implemented for the reasons mentioned.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks for this feedback. This seems like an obvious place for improvement. We could allow employers using external application methods to accept questions via email as you suggested. Note, this is a setting that employers control when posting a job so not all  "Easy Apply" jobs will have Ask a Question enabled. I've set this to review and we'll investigate further at our next planning session. In the meantime, would you mind reporting the job you found with a broken link, if you haven't already?